# what's reason building native quarkus fails

Tags: quarkus

Trying to build native quarkus and there's an error if I add json path https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

```
Call path from entry point to java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(String, byte[], int, int, ProtectionDomain): 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1015)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:878)
    at net.minidev.asm.DynamicClassLoader.defineClass(DynamicClassLoader.java:86)
    at net.minidev.asm.BeansAccessBuilder.bulid(BeansAccessBuilder.java:313)
    at net.minidev.asm.BeansAccess.get(BeansAccess.java:111)
    at net.minidev.json.reader.BeansWriterASM.writeJSONString(BeansWriterASM.java:17)
```

or with option --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime

```
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:603)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:480)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:349)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:508)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:114)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:537)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/security/jacc/EJBMethodPermission
```

Is there anything I can do about it or it's a bug?
using docker to compile, it's working in jvm mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without looking into the library code.

Quarkus does its best to integrate libraries and make them work with native mode, by adding the pieces required by native mode. For native mode limitations, please check this link: https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/Limitations/.

Some libraries may work out of the box without additional configuration. Other require additional configuration to comply with the native image rules.

It seems that the library is trying to dynamically add classes into the ClassLoader, which is unsupported in GraalVM due to the closed world assumption, unless the classes are registered at build time.